# Gunicorn-Supervisor Django Setup Issues

Tags: django, bash, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I am attempting to setup a DigitalOcean Droplet to hold a Django application, and I am following this overview: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/14/how-to-deploy-to-digital-ocean.html

The application runs fine when I execute it via: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

However, once the application is started via `sudo supervisorctl restart all` and I run `sudo supervisorctl status`, I get this, but the app doesn't work when I got to the correct URL:

```
site@SiteDroplet:~$  sudo supervisorctl status Site
Site                      RUNNING   pid 3071, uptime 0:00:19
```

Can someone help?

Here is my directory structure:

```
site@SiteDroplet:~$ cd ../
site@SiteDroplet:/home$ cd ../
site@SiteDroplet:/$ ls
bin   dev  home        initrd.img.old  lib64       media  opt   root  sbin  srv  tmp  var      vmlinuz.old
boot  etc  initrd.img  lib             lost+found  mnt    proc  run   snap  sys  usr  vmlinuz
site@SiteDroplet:/$ ^C
site@SiteDroplet:/$ cd home
site@SiteDroplet:/home$ ls
site
site@SiteDroplet:/home$ cd site
site@SiteDroplet:~$ ls
Site  bin  include  lib  local  logs  run  share
site@SiteDroplet:~$ cd bin
site@SiteDroplet:~/bin$ ls
activate      activate.fish     easy_install      gunicorn_start  pip2    python         python2    wheel
activate.csh  activate_this.py  easy_install-2.7  pip             pip2.7  python-config  python2.7
site@SiteDroplet:~/bin$ cd ../
site@SiteDroplet:~$ cd Site
site@SiteDroplet:~/Site$ ls
Site  app.yaml   forms            interface_login        interface_management  interface_resident  interface_security  objects         requirements.txt  utils
README.md    cron.yaml  interface_admin  interface_maintenance  interface_onsite      interface_root      manage.py           objects_client  templates
site@SiteDroplet:~/Site$ Site is my Django Project Directory
```

**Here is my gunicorn_start file**

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="Site"
DIR=/home/site/Site
USER=site
GROUP=site
WORKERS=3
BIND=unix:/home/site/run/gunicorn.sock
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=Site.settings
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=Site.wsgi
LOG_LEVEL=error

cd $DIR
source ../bin/activate

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DIR:$PYTHONPATH


exec ../bin/gunicorn_start ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $WORKERS \
  --user=$USER \
  --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=$BIND \
  --log-level=$LOG_LEVEL \
  --log-file=-
```

**Here is my supervisor config**

```
[program:Site]
command=/home/site/bin/gunicorn_start
user=site
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/site/logs/gunicorn-error.log
```

**Nginix config**

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/home/site/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    # add here the ip address of your server
    # or a domain pointing to that ip (like example.com or www.example.com)
    server_name 157.230.230.54;

    keepalive_timeout 5;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /home/site/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/site/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/site/static/;
    }

    # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

**Latest gunicorn-error.log**

```
/home/site/Site/../bin/gunicorn_start: line 16: 
/home/site/Site/../bin/gunicorn_start: Argument list too long
/home/site/Site/../bin/gunicorn_start: line 16: / 
/home/site/Site/../bin/gunicorn_start: Success
```

Comment: Well, as your directory structure indicates, you don't have any file called `gunicorn` in the `bin` directory. Did you install it? Is it in your requirements.txt file?

Comment: You can also try this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: @DanielRoseman, yes I have it installed. I fixed the issue I was having initially, that line was the issue I changed it to `gunicorn_start` and now I can start the server, but I am not able to access my site when I run the command to start it, please see the updated question.

Comment: Do you have anything recorded at /home/exactestate/logs/gunicorn-error.log ? How is your nginx configuration ?

Comment: @Josir, the gunicorn-error.log is now posted in my update, it is toggling between stating the `Argument list too long` and `Success`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have such complex setup, here is my account website conf, works like a charm:

```
[group:accounting]
programs=accounting_web

[program:accounting_web]
command = /home/web/.virtualenvs/accounting/bin/gunicorn accounting.wsgi --workers=1 --threads=4 -b unix:/tmp/gunicorn_accounting.sock --log-level=DEBUG --timeout=120
directory = /home/web/accounting
user = web
environment=PATH="/home/web/.virtualenvs/accounting/bin"
```

Comment: would you mind messaging me and helping me understand the process you take to setup what I am asking for with a DO Droplet? I'm brand new to DO and really need help, I have ran through just about every tutorial I can find online and no matter what I seem to do, I am unable to connect to my application without manually using `runserver`, which naturally isn't going to cut it for production.

Comment: Mine runs on a DO droplet too. I suggest you just use a simpler supervisor config like mine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you have a syntax error on gunicorn_start script. My suggestion is to use a smaller command line directly on supervisor .conf.

On nginx.conf:

1) try to change the Servername parameter with a valid URL, for example:

exactestate.com

2) change the sock configuration to TCP:

```
upstream gunicorn_panel {
    # For a TCP configuration:
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0; }

server {
   listen 8080;
```

On supervisor.conf, instead of use the gunicorn_start file, try to write all command directly on the command variable:

```
[program:powerpanel]
command=/home/web/.virtualenvs/accounting/bin/gunicorn powerpanel.wsgi -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -w1 --pythonpath=/home/exactestate/ExactEstate --error-logfile=/home/exactestate/logs/gunicorn-error.log
user=webapp
autostart=true
autorestart=unexpected
startsecs=1
startretries=3
redirect_stderr=true
```